# Why did no-one in the Nolan Universe suspect Bruce Wayne of being Batman?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy

At various times during the trilogy people are trying to find the Batman’s real identity.

Knowing the costs of Batman’s toys wouldn’t someone even suspect one of Gotham’s young rich men?

And the following points:

- the Army knew of the Tumbler, or at the very least people who work for Wayne Enterprises would recognise the equipment
- Coleman Reese
- Bruce Wayne re-appears just as Batman does
- "the Bat" is not a cheap bit of kit, not many people could afford it
- when Harvey Dent asks to take the Batman into custody, no-one notices Bruce stepping forward

Comment: If I were Bruce and Alfred, I'd start a rumour that Batman's toys had been stolen by parties unknown. They could even go so far as to fake a break-in at a Wayne Enterprises warehouse. The Batmobile *is* missing from where it's supposed to be, and who would suspect well-known hedonistic playboy Bruce Wayne?

Comment: ”wouldn’t someone even suspect one of Gotham’s young rich men?” As you almost mentioned in your question, someone did — [Coleman Reese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z6o1GIEsQE). So... what’s your question?

Comment: cause - He is "BATMAN"..

Answer (score 2):

If a "Dark Knight" did actually start a vigilante crime war today or tomorrow, the question wouldn't be "who is this man" it would be "which organisation is behind this, who's bankrolling these guys *(because obviously it can't just be one guy, right?*), who's buying his toys etc

The thought that it's one man working on his own wouldn't be taken seriously